# Nginx/Uwsgi/Flask POST times out if body is too large

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I'm using a dockerimage based on https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker/tree/master/python3.6. I am running a python app inside that accepts a POST, does some processing on the json body, and returns a simple json response back. A post like this:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://10.4.5.168:5002/test -d '{"test": "test"}'
```

works fine. If, however, I post a larger json file, I get a 504: Gateway Timeout.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://10.4.5.168:5002/test -d @some_6mb_file.json
```

I have a feeling that there is an issue with the communication between Nginx and Uwsgi, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

EDIT: I jumped inside the docker container and restarted nginx manually to get better logging. I'm receiving the following error:

> 2018/12/21 20:47:45 [error] 611#611: *1 upstream timed out (110:
>   Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream,
>   client: 10.4.3.168, server: , request: "POST
>   /model/refuel_verification_model/predict HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "uwsgi://unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock", host: "10.4.3.168:5002"

From inside the container, I started a second instance of my Flask app, running without Nginx and Uwsgi and it worked fine. The response took approximately 5 seconds to be returned (due to the processing time of the data.)

Configurations:

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes 1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
daemon off;
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        try_files $uri @app;
    }
    location @app {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /app/static;
    }
}
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d/upload.conf:

```
client_max_body_size 128m;
client_body_buffer_size 128m;
```

Comment: dumb question but have you checked the config files for nginx and Uwsgi? Maybe they just have a timeout parameter you need to increase?

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that while the timeout takes 60 seconds to display, the app stops processing within a second or so. I think the issue is that uwsgi isn't reaponding to nginx.

Comment: How are you starting your container?

Comment: what is `client_max_body_size ` on your nginx setting? It is 1mb by default.

Comment: @2ps I've started the container manually and with a docker compose file (and then running docker-compose up.)

Comment: @hunzter I have client_max_body_size set to 128m. My post size is 5-6mb.

Comment: I mean I need to see the `docker start` command that you are using.  It may be that your start command is not properly starting the docker container.

Comment: @2ps docker run -p 5002:80 myimage. I'm able to make successful requests with small posts, so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: can you share your Nginx config please?

Comment: Try to set uwsgi_read_timeout and uwsgi_send_timeout in NGINX configurations (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.html#uwsgi_send_timeout).

Comment: I think you will need to share your nginx config for further details. Might need to check this:

Comment: @VladimirPoghosyan I tried adding the uwsgi_read_timeout and uwsgi_sent_timeout, but it didn't make a difference.

I added the configuration files in the post.

Comment: New update: I tried posting the same json file with no processing behind the app and it worked fine. I think the issue is that the app performance is extremely degraded when running with Nginx and uwsgi. When running Flask in "development" mode, the app takes <5 seconds to successfully process the data. When running in production (behind nginx/uwsgi), a timeout occurs at 60 seconds.

Comment: Could you post your uwsgi.ini settings? Also, how do you run your application?

Comment: Could be, can you try switch to something else like `gunicorn`? We need to investigate where the problem lies in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with Tensorflow. I had loaded a tensorflow model during the app initialization and then tried to use it later. Because of the threading done by the webserver and the "non-thread-safe" nature of Tensorflow, the processing hung leading to the timeout.

Comment: So how did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this behavior, when proxying to aiohttp (Python) apps.

In my case, in the location block for the proxy, I needed to disable caching:

Removed from the block:

```
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
```

As a result, the working config is something like this:

```
  server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        try_files $uri @app;
    }
    location @app {
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_pass http://myapp;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /app/static;
    }
}
```